# ArcGis Online address related pop-up

Tags: arcgis-online

I am a new user of ArcGIS online. I need to build a map that allows to see the name of the inspector in charge of the area. 
So far I succeeded in creation a map that shows the boundaries of the neighborhoods and a pop-up (very basic) that shows the information required.
I would like to know if there is a way to show the same pop-up (for the corresponding area) when I use the address locator.
Example: If I type the address of my house I would like to see (right away) a pop-up showing the name of the inspector that I should contact.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This would require a custom solution built with the ArcGIS JS API if you wanted the reverse geocode result and the feature query result in the same popup.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to achieve it in ArcGIS Online, but there is a workaround.

1. Do a search with the address locator
2. The locator will zoom to the area
3. Click on the feature layer in the area and the custom popup will appear

In this case there is no need for any custom made webapps or such, but just the basic is enough.